# Proportional sampling via SAS

Tags: sas, sampling

I have 600,000+ observed data that I want to sample proportional to its ZIP codes (the number of ZIP codes in the data are proportional to its population density). The key variables in the data are **ZIP CODE**, **ID**, and **GROUP**.

I need to fix my existing SAS code so that when SAS picks a ZIP CODE, it picks all the records in its **GROUP**. For example, if **ID=2** is selected, I need **ID=1** and **ID=3** as well. Thus, I have all the ZIP codes in **GROUP=1**.

```
ID  GROUP   ZIP
1   1   46227
2   1   46227
3   1   46227
4   2   47620
5   3   47433
6   3   47433
7   3   47433
8   4   46135
9   4   46135
10  5   46202
11  5   46202
12  5   46202
13  5   46202
14  6   46793
15  6   46793
16  7   46202
17  7   46202
18  7   46202
19  8   46409
20  8   46409
21  9   46030
22  9   46030
23  9   46030
24  10  46383
25  10  46383
26  10  46383
```

I have the following SAS code that will sample 1000 obs from the data however it just randomly picks ZIP codes without considering the **GROUP** variable.

```
proc freq data=sample;
    tables zip / out=outfreq noprint;
run;

data newfreq error; set outfreq;
    sampnum=(percent*1000)/100;
    _NSIZE_=round(sampnum, 1);
    sampnum=round(sampnum, .01);
    if _NSIZE_=0 then output error;
    if _NSIZE_=0 then delete;
    output newfreq;
run;

data newfreq2; set newfreq error;
    by zip;
    keep zip _NSIZE_;
run;

proc sort data=newfreq2;
    by zip;
run;

proc sort data=sample;
    by zip;
run;

/* proportional stratified sampling */
proc surveyselect data=sample seed=2020 out=sampout sampsize=newfreq2;
    strata zip;
    id id zip;
run;
```

I hope I am explaining my problem clearly. If not, I'll try to clarify and/or elaborate on things that are unclear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you want to use sampling on the groups then use a lookup to merge back on the zip codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt that seems to work.

```
data test;
    input id group zip;
    cards;
1 1 46227
2 1 46227
3 1 46227
4 2 47620
5 3 47433
6 3 47433
7 3 47433
8 4 46135
9 4 46135
10 5 46202
11 5 46202
12 5 46202
13 5 46202
14 6 46793
15 6 46793
16 7 46202
17 7 46202
18 7 46202
19 8 46409
20 8 46409
21 9 46030
22 9 46030
23 9 46030
24 10 46383
25 10 46383
26 10 46383
;
run;

data test;
    set test;
    rand = ranuni(1200);
run;

proc sort data=test;
    by rand;
run;

/* 10 here is how many cases you want to sample initially */
data test;
    set test;
    if _n_ <= 10 then sample = 1;
    else sample = 0;
run;

proc sort data=test;
    by  group
        descending sample;
run;

data test;
    set test;
    by  group;
    retain keep;    

    if first.group and sample = 1 then keep = 1;
    if first.group and sample = 0 then keep = 0;

    if not first.group then keep = keep;

    drop    rand
            sample;

run;

proc sort data=test;
    by id;
run;
```

As a bonus, here's an R one-liner that will give the same results:

```
# 3 here is the number of cases being sampled
test[test$group %in% (test[sample(1:nrow(test),3),]$group),]
```

Comment: This code seems to work but I don't think the sampled data are not proportional to the number of ZIP codes because I get a lot of ZIPs with low population density.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean.  Are you trying to sample ZIP codes (and return all obs for each ZIP) or do you want a sample stratified BY ZIP code (meaning N obs from each ZIP)?  You might want to see Example 89.4 in the SAS/STAT User's Guide [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_surveyselect_sect026.htm).

Comment: Yeah, I am using stratified sampling method but I want to make sure that I have all ZIP from the same group once a ZIP code is sampled.

Answer (score 0):

This example of 'proportional allocation' on p. 6 of the article referenced below may help:

```
proc surveyselect data=frame out=sampsizes_prop sampsize=400;
 strata cityside **/ alloc=prop**;
run;
```

Article:
    http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2013/SD-01.pdf